# Create async version of sync method

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm currently writing an component where I already have a synchronous method to download files from a server. Here's the signature:

```
public Stream DownloadFile(IData data)
```

Now I wanted to have an async version of this method and tried this:

```
 public async Task<Stream> DownloadFileAsync(IData data)
 {
    Stream stream = null;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      DownloadFile(data);
    });
    return stream;
 }
```

But resharper is showing me a squiggle line under `return stream;` "expression is always null". Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code?

What I want to do is run the DownloadFile method in background and return controlflow to the caller.

EDIT: here is the DownloadFile method:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();

  using (var dtService = new DataTransferService(mConnectionInfo))
  {
    int bytesRead;
    do
    {
      var buffer = new byte[data.ChunkSize];
      bytesRead = dtService.Read(data, buffer);

      if (bytesRead == 0)
      {
        break;
      }

      data.Offset += bytesRead;
      ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    } while (bytesRead > 0);
  }


  return ms;
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't store the stream and return it you only return this: `Stream stream = null;` which is null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Comment: what your trying to do is the sync over async anti pattern, [don't do this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). the whole point of async is that you should implement it everywhere.

Comment: `Task.Run(downloadSomething)` probably is a mistake. Post `DownloadFile()` and then we can see if it can be made async.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks and check my edit :)

Comment: That doesn't help, I don't know what DataTransferService is.  But by the looks of it, forget about making this async. You would only be telling a lie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best option would be to rewrite the `DownloadFile()` method using async I/O, for instance with HttpClient.

Making the current DownloadFile() async with a wrapper is pointless.
If you are stuck between a requirement and the given infrastructure then just fake it while doing the least amount of damage:

```
public Task<Stream> DownloadFileAsync(IData data)  // not 'async', just Task<>
{
    return Task.FromResult(DownloadFile(data));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now. If I were using some .net mechanism to communicate with built in async methods, I could implement my own async method, which will call something like `HttpClient.AnyAsyncMethod`. But in this case the `DataTransferService` will call some proxy to get data from the server, which doesn't expose any async methods. So exposing an async method for me doesn't make any sense, and I will go with your solution and just return a `Task<Stream>`, right?

Comment: If you really need an async version then yes, wrap it with FromResult(). Also see [Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

Answer (score 2):

Because you return `stream` variable, and it's `null` :)

Just return your `Task`

```
public async Task<Stream> DownloadFileAsync(IData data)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => DownloadFile(data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually assign the stream variable:

```
public async Task<Stream> DownloadFileAsync(IData data)
 {
    Stream stream = null;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      // VVV
      stream = DownloadFile(data);
    });
    return stream;
 }
```